How to automatically add to group based on county
I would like to setup CiviCRM on Backdrop to automatically add new contacts to groups based on the county they are listed in. BUT, not every group has a record in so some of these groups are empty, however I still need to be sure that if a contact was to be added that lived in county X, they would automatically be in X group
I have the groups setup, i just dont know how I can add the automatic bit
Thanks in advance

I think you'll need a custom extension to accomplish that. It would be something like: watch for a contact to be created. When a contact is created, get their county information, and then add them to the appropriate group.

You can create a smart group for each county?
Or you can use Civi rules to add and remove people after certain action

the trouble with this is that I dont have someone in each county that I can create the smart group with, so for the counties without anyone in, there wont be an automatic group

You can create dummy contact create a smart group and later delete the dummy contact
